# How to update parent and child table in one transaction in Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Suppose, i have the following table structure for parent,

```
public partial class CustomerDetail
    {
        public CustomerDetail()
        {
            this.DependentDetails = new HashSet<DependentDetail>();

        }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<DependentDetail> DependentDetails { get; set; }

    }
```

And child table structure is,

```
 public partial class DependentDetail
    {
        public int DependentId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Relationship { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual CustomerDetail CustomerDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

If i want to update both the table using Entity framework, how to do that?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

while inserting new record to the database using Entitiy framework

```
var customer=new CustomerDetail();
customer.Title ="Customer";
customer.FirstName ="First";
customer.LastName ="Last";
customer.Gender ="Male";
var dependent=new DependentDetail();
dependent.Relationship ="Test";
.
.
.
customer.DependentDetails.Add(dependent);

while updating dependent

var customer=Repository.find(CustomerId);
//update customer details here
var dependent=customer.DependentDetails.where(x=>x.DependentId ==DependentId).FirstOrDefault();
dependent.RelationShip="Test";

///call save function
```

Comment: I want to update both Customer and Dependant table at one shot.

Comment: thats what call Repository.save() after dependent data is set so that it will update both Customer and Dependent